# Unity Crashing - Couldn't extract exception string from exception

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

every time I run my program unity crashes.  After finding the crash report it's saying (Filename: Assets/SkySpawner.cs Line: 60)
Couldn't extract exception string from exception (another exception of class 'NullReferenceException' was thrown while processing the stack trace)

Here is the code that it seems to not like

```
IEnumerator EnemyGenerator()
{       
    if (actives)
    {       
        var newTransform = transform;  

        if (!first)
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay); 

        if (targets.Count > 0)
        {
            var spawnTarget  = targets[Random.Range(0, targets.Count)];
            newTransform = spawnTarget.transform;
            direction = spawnTarget.transform.localScale;
        }  

        GameObject clone = Instantiate(enemyPool[Random.Range(0, enemyPool.Length)], new Vector3(0,-6,2), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        clone.transform.localScale = direction;

        StartCoroutine(EnemyGenerator());           
    }       
}
```

I have the latest version of unity (4.5.3)

Comment: He mean your code was poorly formatted. I've formatted it for you this time. Next time spend some time in formatting your code, It will improve readability. (Also some users don't even bother to read the code which is poorly formatted).

Comment: Thanks for that, I haven't displayed code in this before